# How to force a program to run as monothread for dynamic analysis?

Tags: binary-analysis, decompilation, thread

I'm reversing a program with x64dbg and ida (I switched from ghidra), hence disassembled and decompiled, I need to understand what is happening with dynamic analysis, but I have a tricky part where about 100 threads are running operations on chunks of a big file.

The program can't run in a VM, since it makes extensive use of AVX AVX2 and GPU.

How can I force the program to run this paralleled part as monothread ? In x64dbg I can suspend threads, but it's very tedious to do this by hand. Is there something I can do with the debuggers or should I change the assembly to launch at most 1 working thread (while allowing several non working threads) ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no generic solution for this problem. You probably need to find the code which decides how many threads to create and see if you can reduce their number or force the processing to occur in the same thread.